# Plotting probability distribution of data using sklearn's KDE function

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, kernel-density, probability-density

I have a number of samples of a variable. I would like to use these samples to plot the probability distribution of the variable. I'm using kernel density estimation with a Gaussian kernel. I'm using `sklearn` library for this purpose. Here is the sample code I have implemented:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.neighbors import KernelDensity

# -- data
init_range = 0.0793
X = np.random.uniform(low=-init_range, high=init_range, size=133280)[:, np.newaxis]

# -- kernel density estimation
kde = KernelDensity(kernel="gaussian", bandwidth=0.2).fit(X)
X_plot = np.linspace(min(X).item(), max(X).item(), 1000)[:, np.newaxis]
log_dens = kde.score_samples(X_plot)

# -- plot density
plt.plot( X_plot[:, 0], np.exp(log_dens), lw=2, linestyle="-")
plt.ylim([0, 2.1])
plt.show()
```

Below is the resulting output:

[image]

As you can see, the value on the y axis is above one. Hence, the y axis is NOT showing the probability distribution. I further plotted the histogram for this data:

```
# -- plot hist
n_bins = 40
weights = np.ones_like(X) / float(len(X))
prob, bins, _ = plt.hist(X, n_bins, density=False, histtype='step', color='red', weights=weights)
plt.show()
```

and the result is below:

[image]

which makes sense as  the bins sum up to one: `0.025*40=1`

I'm having a hard time understanding why my kde plot is not a distribution. How can I fix this? Is there a normalization step that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

First, if you extend the limits of your X_plot axis (i.e. `X_plot = np.linspace(-1, 1,...)`), you'll see that your KDE estimates a rather tall gaussian, and the area under curve is still 1.
Density values over 1 are perfectly legal, since the assumed distribution is continuous: there's no real probabilities for the exact points, and you should not treat your Y values as such; estimated probabilty for an interval is the respective area under curve.

Sample code to verify the estimated probability of hitting 0-0.004 range (roughly the same width as your histogram bin):

```
import scipy.integrate as integrate
interval = np.linspace(0, 0.004, 1000)[:, np.newaxis]
log_dens = kde.score_samples(interval)
print(integrate.trapz(np.exp(log_dens), interval[:,0]))
```

Second, once you check the area under curve you'll see your current hyperparameters aren't yielding too accurate of an estimation, reducing the bandwith or choosing a different algo might help.

You can also apply grid search to find the least inaccurate algo and bandwith, though this will take a good amount of time unless you reduce your sample size; also, choosing a narrow bandwidth may result in undersmoothing.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
grid = GridSearchCV(KernelDensity(), {'kernel':['gaussian', 'tophat'],'bandwidth': np.logspace(-2, 0, 10)}, cv=5, n_jobs=-1)
grid.fit(X)
print(f"best hyperparameters: {grid.best_params_}")
kde = grid.best_estimator_
```